# Can't start PHP on Win via HTA with setx PATH and php -S commands

Tags: php, cmd, path, hta

I've created HTA file to install and start PHP on Windows. If there is already the `my_app_folder/php` folder with some version of PHP, via HTA file we only have 1) to set the Win `PATH` variable with path to the PHP folder, 2) go to the `/my_app_folder` where is `index.php` and 3) to run the `php -S` CMD-command.

So here is the code of my testing HTA file:

```
<script>
var objUserInfo = new ActiveXObject('WScript.network');
var pathToUserFolder = 'C:\\Users\\'+objUserInfo.UserName+'\\';

var WShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');

WShell.Run('cmd /c setx PATH '+pathToUserFolder+'my_app_folder\\php',0,true);

WShell.CurrentDirectory = pathToUserFolder+'my_app_folder';
WShell.Run('cmd /c php -S localhost:80',0,false);

setTimeout(function() {     
    WShell.Run('chrome -url http://localhost:80', 0, false);
}, 17000);
</script>
```

If I open this HTA file, the `PATH` variable is being added successfully, but the `php.exe` process is not being runned. However if the `PATH` variable already exists and I open the file, the `php.exe` process is being runned.

ps. I noticed that the PHP server is ready at least 17 seconds after we runned the `php -S` command, so as you see I use `setTimeout()` before opening the browser and following by the `localhost` address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's enough to use full path to `php.exe` in the CMD-command if we have some troubles with the PATH variable:

```
WShell.Run('cmd /c C:\\my_app_folder\\php\\php.exe -S localhost:80',0,false);
```